# How to fix cascade cycles when it is not in there?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Why do I get a cascade cycle error in MSSQL?

I have a couple of tables:

**Configuration**
Root table no reference to other tables.

**User**
This table references configuration.

**Group**
This table references configuration.

**Member**
This table references one group and one user.

**Owner**
This table references one group and one user.

All references are DELETE: CASCADE so when I remove a configuration, all users and groups will be deleted, and those should delete all member/ownerships.

[Update: 09:43] Added image

[image]

[Update: 09:46] Added code example

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(q => q.Configuration).WithMany(q => q.Users).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasOne(q => q.Configuration).WithMany(q => q.Groups).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasOne(q => q.User).WithMany(q => q.Members).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasOne(q => q.Group).WithMany(q => q.Members).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasOne(q => q.User).WithMany(q => q.Owners).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasOne(q => q.Group).WithMany(q => q.Owners).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I don't see a cycle, but why can't I do this?

Comment: Post the DDL of your tables, along with sample data, and then show the behaviour your getting (by replcaiting it with SQL) and explain the bahaviour you expect. We can't see your data, and we only have a very vague definition of your tables; not enough that we can help you with.

Comment: Does the extended information help?

Comment: Picture suggests that you have multiple paths. SQL Server doesn't support multiple branches like that.

Comment: SQL Server's error message for this is misleading -- it will, in general, reject any setup where a delete might have to go through two different paths to reach the same record, even if there's no actual cycling.

Comment: What can I do about it? Only creating a trigger?

Comment: Run query generated by Entity in SQL Server Management Studio which has better error messages than c#.